# Develop Admin Panel Page

Tags: posts, wp-admin, admin-menu, dashboard

How to develop a Admin Panel Page in WordPress DashBoard like All Posts page ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**WP_List_Table**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_list_table/) class is used to generate the List Tables that populate WordPress' various admin screens. It has an advantage over previous implementations in that it can be dynamically altered with AJAX and may be hooked in future WordPress releases.

**If you want to use this class pay attention to this warning by Wordpress.**

> **This class's access is marked as private**. That means it is not intended for use by plugin and theme developers as it is subject to change without warning in any future WordPress release. **If you would still like to make use of the class, you should make a copy to use and distribute with your own project, or else use it at your own risk**.

Here are **[Tutorial 1](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-wp_list_table-to-create-wordpress-admin-tables/) and [Tutorial 2](https://wpengineer.com/2426/wp_list_table-a-step-by-step-guide/)**, that may help you start.